# C# message box's. can the text be adjusted?

Tags: c#, messagebox

Can you center text in a message box? or does the whole message have to be left aligned?
also how do you make some text in a message box bold well leaving the remainder of the text standard?

Comment: An example for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569489/easiest-way-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-which-returns-a-value/9569772#9569772

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can`t restyle the default message box. You can create your custom message box(Dialog) and call it with .ShowDialog().

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't `center` or `bold` the text in `Message Box`

You can do it over [Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397515(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: could you please post a code example of the usage of DialogBox in a c# environment. I ask, as others will ask this question and it would help them to have an example of code to look at.

Comment: Follow the `C# Customized Dialog Box` in this http://www.dotnetperls.com/customized-dialog link